# How to fix : 'com.xxx.xxxx.MainActivity' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity' less

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

I can't run my app because I've got issues in my Manifest file. It says : 
'com.diridou.mescoiffeurs.MainActivity' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Validates resource references inside Android XML files

MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity but I can't resolve AppcompactActivity

Also I have no graddle issues.

I added : 
1°

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

in my graddle.properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.diridou.mescoiffeurs">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

My graddle files looks like :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.diridou.mescoiffeurs"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    /*Dependencies de base */
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    /*Firebase*/
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gradle.properties, you have the flag set to use AndroidX, however, you do not import any AndroidX resources. Instead, you are using the support dependencies. To fix this, in your `build.gradle`, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) for any dependencies you have declared, and replace them with the corresponding `androidx` dependency.

Comment: @EliWhite Thanks I've used the button in Android Studio " migrated to AndroidX" and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

That `MainActivity` does exactly nothing ...

You must provide a public constructor - and it is common to override method `onCreate()`.

Besides, all of those `com.android.support` dependencies need to be manually replaced;

Current versions of Firebase use `androidx` internally (which makes the Jetifier useless).